# Upload video in server

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

In my app I'm recording a video in iPad and I want to upload it to my server.  Kindly let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: simple Question and simple answer yes you can achieve this with iOS SDK. now try some code on your end any problem put the code here surely will get the solution.

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923885/how-to-upload-video-file-to-server-in-iphone-application

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, have you tried anything? Done any research? Have you even googled it? (Upload video to server objective-c). Please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq, once you have made some effort to do something then come back and ask the question.

Comment: Hi all.. Thanks for the response.. I dont know how to start that was the reason. And I will try from my end let you know if any issues.

Comment: so u are going to upload video "IN SERVER" !! ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your Request Dictionary with File Object in it, later postWith: function will manipulate you Video binding task

```
NSDictionary *requestDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"FirstObjectValue",@"FirstKey",
                             @"Second Object",@"Second Key",
                             @"myFileParameterToReadOnServerSide",@"file", nil]; // This line indicate ,POST data has file to attach
[self postWith:requestDict];
```

Following Function will read all your parameters from dictionary of objects you want to POST if you want to send Video then add "file" key in your dictionary that identifies there is some file to be send with request

```
- (void)postWith:(NSDictionary *)post_vars
{
#warning Add your Webservice URL here        
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YourHostString"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSString *boundary = @"----1010101010";

    //  define content type and add Body Boundry
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [post_vars keyEnumerator];
    NSString *key;
    NSString *value;
    NSString *content_disposition;

    while ((key = (NSString *)[enumerator nextObject])) {

        if ([key isEqualToString:@"file"]) {

            value = (NSString *)[post_vars objectForKey:key];
            //  ***     Write Your Image Name Here  ***
            // Covnert Video to Data and bind to your post request
#warning Add your Video From Path 
            NSString *videoFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
            NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoFilePath];

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\";\r\nfilename=\"testUploadFile.mp4\"\r\n\r\n",value] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:postData];
        } else {
            value = (NSString *)[post_vars objectForKey:key];

            content_disposition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key];
            [body appendData:[content_disposition dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        }

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }

    //Close the request body with Boundry
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", body.length] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Length"];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);        
}
```